# Avoid escaping in Yeoman Generator

Tags: generator, yeoman

I want to replace a template in the YEOMAN Generator with the string 'lr_task->'.

But in the result file is the string escaped to 'lr_task-&gt' (html like).

I'm using this.fs.copyTpl( ) for the replacement of the templates.

How can I avoid this escaping?

Best regards
Frank

Answer (score 0):

I found the soultion.
I used the placeholder <%**=** placeholder%>.
But I have to use <%**-** placeholder%> to avoid the escaping.

```
<%= escapes the value
<%- escapes not the value
```